# How to make Halide use the sliding window optimization?

Tags: c++, halide

I'm learning Halide and I'm struggling with the scheduling part. I'm trying to make Halide do the same thing as a hand coded implementation of the algorithm. I don't want to parallelize it but to vectorize it, but first I wanted to understand how to make Halide do a simple sliding window. I tried different things:

- splitting the sum in x and y and then different scheduling
- defining the sum in recursive form (snippet at the end)

But I can't get it to produce anything similar. It boils down to a simple variation of a mean filter. So, how do I schedule Halide code to actually do a sliding window like the original code?

This is the code:

```cpp
void lmrCPU(const cv::Mat& image, std::vector<uint16_t>& vertSum, int xMin, int xMax, int yMin, int yMax, int lmrSize, cv::Mat& lmr ) {
    int lmrWidth = 2*lmrSize + 1;
    int area = lmrWidth*lmrWidth;

    vertSum.resize(image.cols);

    // Zero contents of vertSum
    memset(vertSum.data(), 0, vertSum.size()*sizeof(uint16_t));

    for (int yy = yMin; yy < yMin + lmrWidth; ++yy)
    {
        for (int x=0; x<image.cols; x++) vertSum[x] += unsigned(image.ptr<uint8_t>(yy)[x]);
    }

    for (int y = yMin; y <= yMax; y++)
    {
        if (y > yMin + lmrSize && y <= yMax - lmrSize)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
                vertSum[x] += unsigned(image.at<uint8_t>(y + lmrSize, x)) - unsigned(image.at<uint8_t>(y - lmrSize - 1, x));
        }

        unsigned sum = 0;

        int xx, x, xxBack;
        for (xx = xMin; xx < xMin + lmrWidth; xx++) sum += vertSum[xx];

        for (x = xMin; x < xMin + lmrSize; x++)
            lmr.at<int>(y, x) = int(image.at<uint8_t>(y, x)) * area - sum;

        sum -= vertSum[xMin + 2*lmrSize]; // take off ready for next loop

        for (x = xMin + lmrSize, xxBack = x - lmrSize, xx = x + lmrSize; x < xMax - lmrSize; x++, xx++, xxBack++)
        {
            sum += vertSum[xx];
            lmr.at<int>(y, x) = int(image.at<uint8_t>(y,x))*area - sum;
            sum -= vertSum[xxBack];
        }

        sum += vertSum[xx];

        for ( ; x <= xMax; x++)
            lmr.at<int>(y, x) = int(image.at<uint8_t>(y,x))*area - sum;
    }
}
```

```cpp
#include "Halide.h"

namespace {
    class LMR : public Halide::Generator<LMR> {
    public:
        ImageParam input{UInt(8), 2, "input"};

        Param<int32_t> xMin{"xMin"}, xMax{"xMax"};
        Param<int32_t> yMin{"yMin"}, yMax{"yMax"};
        Param<int32_t> lmrSize{"lmrSize"};

        Var x{"x"}, y{"y"};

        Func build() {
            auto lmrWidth = 2*lmrSize + 1;
            auto area = lmrWidth*lmrWidth;

            Halide::Func input_int32 ("input_int32");
            input_int32(x, y) = Halide::cast<int32_t>(input(x, y));

            Halide::Func input_uint16 ("input_uint16");
            input_uint16(x, y) = Halide::cast<uint16_t>(input(x, y));

            Halide::Expr clamped_x = Halide::clamp(x, xMin, xMax);
            Halide::Expr clamped_y = Halide::clamp(y, yMin, yMax);

            Halide::Expr lmr_x = Halide::clamp(x, xMin+lmrSize, xMax-lmrSize);
            Halide::Expr lmr_y = Halide::clamp(y, yMin+lmrSize, yMax-lmrSize);

            Halide::RDom box (-lmrSize, lmrWidth, "box");

            Halide::Func vertSum ("vertSum");
            vertSum(x, y) = Halide::undef<uint16_t>();
            {
                Halide::RDom ry (yMin+lmrSize+1, yMax-yMin-2*lmrSize, "ry");
                vertSum(x, yMin+lmrSize) = Halide::cast<uint16_t>(0);//Halide::sum(input_uint16(x, yMin+lmrSize+box), "sum_y");
                vertSum(x, yMin+lmrSize) += input(x, yMin+lmrSize+box);
                vertSum(x, ry) = vertSum(x, ry-1) + input_uint16(x, ry+lmrSize) - input_uint16(x, ry-1-lmrSize);
            }

            Halide::Func sumLmr ("sumLmr");
            sumLmr(x, y) = Halide::undef<uint16_t>();
            {
                Halide::RDom rx (xMin+lmrSize+1, xMax-xMin-2*lmrSize, "rx");
                sumLmr(xMin+lmrSize, y) = Halide::cast<uint16_t>(0);//Halide::sum(vertSum(xMin+lmrSize+box, y), "sum_x");
                sumLmr(xMin+lmrSize, y) += vertSum(xMin+lmrSize+box, y);
                sumLmr(rx, y) = sumLmr(rx-1, y) + vertSum(rx+lmrSize, y) - vertSum(rx-1-lmrSize, y);
            }
            Halide::Func lmr ("lmr");
            lmr(x, y) = input_int32(clamped_x, clamped_y)*area - Halide::cast<int32_t>(sumLmr(lmr_x, lmr_y));

            vertSum
                .fold_storage(y, 1)
                .store_root()
                .compute_at(lmr, y);

            sumLmr
                .fold_storage(x, 1)
                .store_at(lmr, y)
                .compute_at(lmr, x);

            return lmr;
        }
    };

    HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(LMR, "lmr")
}
```

This is the output of `lmr.print_loop_nest();`

```
store vertSum:
  produce lmr:
    for y:
      produce vertSum:
        for y:
          for x:
            vertSum(...) = ...
        for x:
          vertSum(...) = ...
        for x:
          for box:
            vertSum(...) = ...
        for x:
          for ry:
            vertSum(...) = ...
      consume vertSum:
        store sumLmr:
          for x:
            produce sumLmr:
              for y:
                for x:
                  sumLmr(...) = ...
              for y:
                sumLmr(...) = ...
              for y:
                for box:
                  sumLmr(...) = ...
              for y:
                for rx:
                  sumLmr(...) = ...
            consume sumLmr:
              lmr(...) = ...
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, how to schedule the Halide code to generate a sliding window like the original code. I'll edit the post to be more clear about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what was the problem. Halide doesn't know how to optimize the code with a variable window size. By hardcoding the lmrWidth it generates the correct code. The final code looks like this:

```cpp
#include "Halide.h"

namespace {
    class LMR : public Halide::Generator<LMR> {
    public:
        ImageParam input{UInt(8), 2, "input"};

        Param<int32_t> xMin{"xMin"}, xMax{"xMax"};
        Param<int32_t> yMin{"yMin"}, yMax{"yMax"};
        Param<int32_t> lmrSize{"lmrSize"};

        Var x{"x"}, y{"y"};

        Func build() {
            auto lmrWidth = 11;//2*lmrSize + 1;
            auto area = lmrWidth*lmrWidth;

            Halide::Expr clamped_x = Halide::clamp(x, xMin, xMax);
            Halide::Expr clamped_y = Halide::clamp(y, yMin, yMax);

            Halide::Expr lmr_x = Halide::clamp(x, xMin+lmrSize, xMax-lmrSize);
            Halide::Expr lmr_y = Halide::clamp(y, yMin+lmrSize, yMax-lmrSize);

            Halide::Func sum_y ("sum_y");
            {
                Halide::Expr sum = input(x, y-lmrSize);
                for (int i=1;i<lmrWidth;i++) {
                    sum = sum + Halide::cast<uint16_t>(input(x, y-lmrSize+i));
                }
                sum_y(x, y) = sum;
            }

            Halide::Func sum_x ("sum_x");
            {
                Halide::Expr sum = sum_y(x-lmrSize, y);
                for (int i=1;i<lmrWidth;i++) {
                    sum = sum + sum_y(x-lmrSize+i, y);
                }
                sum_x(x, y) = sum;
            }

            Halide::Func sumLmr("sumLmr");
            sumLmr(x, y) = sum_x(x, y);

            Halide::Func output("output");
            output(x, y) = Halide::cast<int32_t>(input(clamped_x, clamped_y))*area - Halide::cast<int32_t>(sumLmr(lmr_x, lmr_y));

            sum_x.compute_root();
            sum_y.compute_at(sum_x, y);
            output.vectorize(x, 16);

            return output;
        }
    };

    HALIDE_REGISTER_GENERATOR(LMR, "lmr")
}
```

Comment: Now to figure out how to avoid hardcoding the window size

Comment: Have you figured out the solution for this situation? It happened with my code in many cases too, regarding a lot of 'variable' parameters

Comment: I ended up using the JIT instead, that way the window is "hardcoded" for Halide. If you need AOT you might want to check http://mit-gfx.github.io/recfilter/

Comment: thanks, it is not actually about filtering, more about the variability. jit is sadly not an option, so will have to recompile each time i guess

Answer (score 2):

A concise and fundamental, if a bit terse, answer to your question is "In order to use sliding window, the storage and compute for the computation must be scheduled at different loop levels." (This is done using a `compute_at` and then `store_at` in the schedule.) In effect one moves the storage further out from the compute so it will have larger bounds than one unit of computation. Then, if a certain set of constraints are met, such as a power of two size window, Halide will automatically infer and generate the sliding window. The sliding window can be made larger using the `fold_storage` directive.

The tests:
    https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/correctness/sliding_window.cpp
and:
https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/test/correctness/sliding_reduction.cpp

demonstrate the split storage/compute scheduling.

I'm not sure you will have all the names available that you need to do this scheduling if you use the `sum` inline reduction.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated the code with what looks like should be the equilavent Halide code to the handcoded one. The problem is that Halide ends up regenerating all vertSum and sumLmr in each iteration instead of doing a sliding window and reuse the previous values. It looks like https://github.com/halide/Halide/pull/1546 might help but I think I should be able to generate something that works as fast as the manual version without too much trouble.

Comment: I think I narrowed down to a more specific issue, the current code in the question it almost does what I want. The problem is that it's recalculating the first 2 updates inside every loop instead of doing once in the root and then using the recursive form inside. Is there a way to make only part of the update to be evaluated outside the loop?